# Identical code not working the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$('#as_tags_in_l67').tagging({});    
$('.type-zone').attr({contenteditable: true,class:"type-zone",placeholder:"tags",required:'',type:"text",});
      
//validation form    
var validateForm = (function() {
  var options = {};
  var classError = 'error';
    var showFieldValidation = function(input, inputIsValid) {
        if (!inputIsValid) {
            if (!input.parentNode.className || input.parentNode.className.indexOf(options.classError)==-1) {
            input.parentNode.className += ' ' + options.classError
             if(input.classList.contains("til_l67_text"))
            {
               var d = document.getElementById("de_scri_tit_11");
      d.classList.add("w_te_88")
               $("#de_scri_tit_11").css('display','block')
            }
            else{
            var d = document.getElementById("de_scri_tag_11");
            d.classList.add("w_tg_11");
            $("#de_scri_tag_11").css('display','block')
            }}
        } else {
            var regError = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+options.classError+'(\\s|$)');
            input.parentNode.className =              input.parentNode.className.replace(regError, '');
          
            if(input.classList.contains("til_l67_text"))
            {
       var d = document.getElementById("de_scri_tit_11");
                d.classList.remove("w_te_88");
                $("#de_scri_tit_11").css('display','none');
            }
            else{
                var d = document.getElementById("de_scri_tag_11");
                d.classList.remove("w_tg_11");
                $("#de_scri_tag_11").css('display','none');
            }}};
     var testInputText = function(input) {
        var fieldHasError = false;
        var mailReg = new RegExp('^[0-9a-zA-Z_.-]', 'gi');      
        if (!mailReg.test(input.value)) {
            showFieldValidation(input, false);
            return false;
        } else {
            showFieldValidation(input, true);
            return true;
        }}; 
    var prepareElements = function() {
        var elements = options.form.getElementsByClassName('til_l67_text');
        [].forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
            element.removeAttribute('required');
            element.className += ' required';
            if (element.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT') {
                var type = element.type.toUpperCase();

                if (type == 'TEXT') {
                    element.addEventListener('keyup', function() {testInputText(element)});
                    element.addEventListener('blur', function() {testInputText(element)});
                }}});   
    };
 
  var prepareElementsTag = function() {
        var elements = options.form.getElementsByClassName('type-zone');
        [].forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
            element.removeAttribute('required');
            element.className += ' required';
            if (element.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT') {
                var type = element.type.toUpperCase();
                if (type == 'TEXT') {
                    element.addEventListener('keyup', function() {testInputText(element)});
                    element.addEventListener('blur', function() {testInputText(element)});
                }}});        
     }; 
var formSubmit = function() {
    options.form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var validated = true;
        var elements = options.form.querySelectorAll('.required');
        [].forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
            if (element.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT') {
                var type = element.type.toUpperCase();                            
                if (type == 'TEXT') {
                    if (!testInputText(element)) validated = false;
                }}});                 
        if (validated) {
            this.submit();
        } else {
            return false;
        }});    
};    
    var init = function(_options) {
        options = {
            form : _options.form || null,
            classError : _options.classError || 'error'  
        }
        if (options.form == null || options.form == undefined || options.form.length==0) {
            console.warn('validateForm: Źle przekazany formularz');
            return false;
        }
        prepareElements();
  prepareElementsTag()
  formSubmit();
 };
    return {
        init : init
    }
})();
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var form = document.querySelector('.form');
    validateForm.init({form : form})
});
```

```css
.tagging {
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
 margin-left:55px;
 width:190px;
 font-size:14px;
 font-family:Arial;
 min-height:28px;
 border:1px solid #33b2ff;
 position:absolute;
 top:55px;
    left:5px;
}
.til_l67
{
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
  }
.as_tags_lab_l67
{
    position:absolute;
    top:55px;
  }
.post_ans_976
{
    position:absolute;
    top:105px;
  }
.til_l67_text
{
 border: 0 none;
 height: 25px;
 width: auto;
 min-width: 180px;
 display: inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
    left:60px;
 font-size:16px;
 font-family:Arial;
   border:1px solid #33b2ff;
  }
.tagging.editable {
 cursor: text;
}
.tag {
 background: no-repeat scroll 2px 7px rgba(190,253,190,1);
 background-image: url(tag_left.png);
 border-radius:11px 0 0 11px;
 border:1px solid rgba(150,213,150,1);
 color:rgba(12,18,151,1);
 cursor: default;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 white-space: nowrap;
 padding: 5px 27px 8px 21px;
 margin: 3px 5px 0 0;
 height:13px
}
.tag .tag-i {
 color: #999;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 20px;
 height: 15px;
 line-height: 15px;
 position: absolute;
 top:7px;
 right: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 15px;
}
.tag .tag-i:hover {
 color: #333;
 border:1px solid #666;
 border-radius:50%;
 top:6px;
 right:4px;
 background-color:rgba(235,235,235,1);
}
.type-zone {
 border: 0 none;
 height: 15px;
 width: 160px;
 display: inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:4px;
 font-size:16px;
 font-family:Arial;
}
.type-zone:focus {
 outline: none;
}
#de_scri_tit_11
{
 height: 30px;
 font-size:14px;
 width:240px;
 position:absolute;
 left:300px;
 top:3px;
 color:#fff;
 font-family:Arial;
 display:none;
 background-color:#DB083E;
 border-radius:8px;
 padding:5px;
 border:3px solid #666;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.w_te_88:before
{
 content:'Tiltle must have min 150 char.'
}
#de_scri_tag_11
{
 height: 30px;
 font-size:14px;
 width:240px;
 position:absolute;
 left:300px;
 top:65px;
 color:#fff;
 font-family:Arial;
 display:none;
 background-color:#DB083E;
 border-radius:8px;
 padding:5px;
 border:3px solid #666;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.w_tg_11:before
{
 content:'Max 4 tags'
}
.form .error input[type=text]{
    color: #DB083E;
    border-color: #DB083E;
    background: #FFEDED url(img/error.png) right center no-repeat;
    background-position: calc(100% - 10px) center;
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px red; 

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sniperwolf/taggingJS/master/tagging.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
 <div class="ask_con_area67">
  
  <div id="til_bo_x43">
   <label class="til_l67">Title</label>
   <input class="til_l67_text" type="text" placeholder="title" autocomplete="off" required />
   <div id="de_scri_tit_11"></div>
  </div>    
  <div id="con_ask_ex87">
  </div>  
  <div class="as_tags_cho99">
   <label class="as_tags_lab_l67">Tags</label>
   <div data-tags-input-name="tag" id="as_tags_in_l67"></div>   
   <div id="de_scri_tag_11"></div>
  </div>
 <button class="post_ans_976">Submit</button> 
 </div> 
 </form>
```

Hello,
I have one question, because I am beginner and this situation is weird for me.
Could you explain me why the code on Stack snippet working ok, but on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0h2q6zby/2/ not working. And the problem is in validation form, correct form is when input is empty and you blur shows red border (like snippet below)

Comment: looks like there is some issue with `document.addEventListener` as it doesn't get executed on jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select `no wrap - in <body>`. Below is an explanation of the features available to wrap the code

**onLoad**

wrap the code so it will run in onLoad window event

**onDomReady**

wrap the code so it will run in onDomReady window event

**no wrap - in**

do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in  section

**no wrap - in**

do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in  section

Your code is working fine in jsfiddle. Check this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/0h2q6zby/3/)

Comment: thank you, I have last question, maybe obiously, in my "application" is the same problem, in my html or javascript code can do the  same no-wrap-in<body> ?

Comment: yes in application it is better to wrao code at the end of the body. This will decrease loading time. `<body> // Rest of code <script> //All js code</script></body>`